# What is the difference between adding CMS Static Block into CMS Page Content & Design?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, cms-pages

> What is the difference between adding CMS Static Block into CMS Page -> Content and  CMS Page -> Design?

Comment: if you are talking about output, then there is no difference.

Comment: CMS Page -> Content - Here you can set your cms page content.
CMS Page -> Design  - Here can set your cms page layout.